# Organisational structure parent-child relationship

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a organisational structure for a company. However, my current VBA script does not have a parent-child relationship eg(Trainer under Team Leader). How can i create the relationship in macro and display it in the organisational structure? In the picture below, Jodan and Sky are supposed to be under Jane.
VBA code:

```
 org()
 org Macro
'Macro to generate organization chart
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+j
'
    Dim ogSALayout As SmartArtLayout
    Dim QNode As SmartArtNode
    Dim QNodes As SmartArtNodes
    Dim t As Integer
    Set ogSALayout = Application.SmartArtLayouts(92) 'reference to organization chart
    Set ogShp = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddSmartArt(ogSALayout)
    Set QNodes = ogShp.SmartArt.AllNodes
    t = QNodes.Count

    While QNodes.Count < t
    QNodes(QNodes.Count).Delete
    Wend

    While QNodes.Count < Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    QNodes.Add.Promote
    Wend

    For i = 1 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    'Promote and demote nodes to put them at the proper level.

    While QNodes(Range("A" & i)).Level < Range("C" & i).Value
        QNodes(Range("A" & i)).Demote
    Wend

    'Copy the cell text to the node.
    QNodes(Range("A" & i)).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = Range("B" & i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image: Structure]

Comment: A lookup table, first column is item under scrutiny, second column is parent, 3rd or more columns are children.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adoGOvKTzmM

Comment: Actually from this data you cannot generate the tree. The data only shows which level each person is but it doesn't reflect any relationships. Here you cannot dermine from the data wether `Jordan` and `Sky` are children of `Jane` or of `Kite` (could also be one each). Therefore you would need a column that sepecifies for each name the corresponding parents name. Then you can generate a tree.

Comment: You can add in next columns numbers of levels which are under and so on

Comment: @KubaDo numbers of levels are not sufficient to build a tree. You need true Child-Parent-Relations to build a tree.